# Symfony 1.4 Propel Join Criteria needs peer constants

Tags: php, sql, symfony-1.4, propel

I want to share something quite annoying with you, because this problem cost me a lot of time to understand:

Lets start with something quite simple:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(PersonPeer::ID, 123);
PersonPeer::doSelect($c);

$c = new Criteria();
$c->add("person.ID", 123);
PersonPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Of course, both works because PersonPeer::ID is just a representation of the string "person.ID".

Now do a Join:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(PersonPeer::ID, 123);
$c->addJoin(PersonPeer::ID, OrderPeer::PERSON_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
$c->add(OrderPeer::AMOUNT, 10);
PersonPeer::doSelect($c);
```

quite simple, this works... now replace some constants:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(PersonPeer::ID, 123);
$c->addJoin("person.ID", OrderPeer::PERSON_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
$c->add("order.AMOUNT", 10);
PersonPeer::doSelect($c);
```

... still works.
But now replace all constants:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add("person.ID", 123);
$c->addJoin("person.ID", "order.PERSON_ID", Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
$c->add("order.AMOUNT", 10);
fbPersonPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Surprise surprise, this throws a PropelException:

```
wrapped: Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined table: order
```

So why the hell is that? The criterias are the exact same, but it doesn't work!

The solution: it seems that Symfony hasn't loaded the OrderPeer!?
Here comes the funny "Bugfix":

```
OrderPeer::AMOUNT;
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add("person.ID", 123);
$c->addJoin("person.ID", "order.PERSON_ID", Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
$c->add("order.AMOUNT", 10);
fbPersonPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Just call something of the OrderPeer and now it works again.

Pretty freaky, isn't it? It's not a bug, it's a feature?! :D

Does anybody has a better solution or explanation!?
Is it a Symfony 1.4 or a Propel problem?

Comment: Are you sure about your constant value ?

Comment: Yes, look at the last two examples. The constants aren't the problem. Instead of "OrderPeer::AMOUNT" I could also call "OrderPeer::doSomething()" and now it works because the Peer is loaded.

Comment: Oh, it's not an issue so, just your autoloader implementation.